# Permission denied with user ubuntu but not with user www-data on .csv file

Tags: php, csv, ubuntu

I'm seeing weird Ubuntu permission issues only on a single .csv file when trying to access with php. The file is list.csv, owned by ubuntu:www-data, and ubuntu user is part of www-data group. The rest of the site works fine, no permission issues, but I see the following error when trying to load this file with php:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'SplFileObject::__construct(xxx/list.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied'
```

If i do chown www-data:www-data list.csv, i can load with php. Why is this file not being loaded by php if owned by ubuntu, even if ubuntu is part of www-data group?

Additionally, I can open this file as ubuntu user (vi list.csv) read and write.

Edit: Permissions on the file are: -rwxr-xr-x  1 ubuntu www-data

Edit again: Changed permissions to 0644 -rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu www-data no luck

Edit some more: File lives in a directory that has x permission:
drwxr-xr-x  3 ubuntu   www-data 4096 Jul 28 23:09 content/

Not sure it has anything to do with execute permissions as I can change owner to www-data:www-data and the file gets loaded. It would seem its something to do with user ubuntu owning the file and not www-data

Edit: Its this line of code that errors out, trying to load .csv file into php SplFileObject:

```
SplFileObject::__construct("xxx/content/list.csv");
```

Comment: what are the full permissions for the file?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Try changing the permissions to 644, execution is not necessary on a csv file.

Comment: Does it work if you change the permissions to 664 (i.e. `rw-r--r--`)?

Comment: Is the file perhaps inside a folder that doesn't have x permissions?

Comment: How are you trying to load the file? What functions are involved here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in the OP that the only difference between the owner and group is `write` permission (you have tried `xr` and `r` with the group). So, I suspect your `PHP` is trying to open the file in `write` mode.

To confirm this try:

```
$myCSV = new SplFileInfo('YOUR CSV');
$myCSV->isReadable(); // should be true
$myCSV->isWritable();   //expecting this to be false
```

Edit: If that's whats going with your program you can open the file just in read mode using: `$myCSV->openFile('r')`

Comment: That was it! Adding write permissions to group fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: there is a troubleshooting checklist for this kind of problems : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Your server might have the PHP `open_basedir` parameter set which would prevent access to any files outside of this directory.

To verify this have a look into your relevant php.ini file (for example /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini) and check if the `open_basedir` line is set.

Comment: open_basedir is not set:;open_basedir =